# Folder and File Security on Android

Tags: android

I am newbie to the platform of android. I am intending to make an application that will protected your desired folders and files through password to keep it access limited to your application. You cant access the content through file explorers on android and via SD card reader. I also want to know how to make a background service that cant be killed by task killers.

Looking forward for your comments and reply
Best Regards,

Comment: Did you tried any of the encryption techniques??

Answer (score 0):

> I am intending to make an application that will protected your desired folders and files through password to keep it access limited to your application. You cant access the content through file explorers on android and via SD card reader.

What you want is impossible, except perhaps via firmware modifications, since it is a massive security violation.